# Difference of amount of two virtual column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to get the difference between two-column, here is my current query :

```
select customer_id as customers_id, sum(amount) as manual_amount,
       (select amount from customers where id = customers_id) as current_wallet_amount
FROM wallet_transactions 
where customer_id = 14438 
group by wallet_transactions.customer_id
```

The result that I am getting is attached below:

[image]

What I need is the difference of manual amount and current_wallet_amount. Any help would be highly appreciable

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh MySQL is specified in Subject. Version is not specified...

Comment: @Akina, I know, but OP needs tag properly anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  wt.customer_id AS customers_id, 
  SUM(wt.amount) AS manual_amount, 
  ANY_VALUE(customers.amount) AS current_wallet_amount,
  (SUM(wt.amount) - ANY_VALUE(customers.amount)) AS diff_amount
FROM wallet_transactions AS wt
JOIN customers ON customers.id = wt.customer_id
WHERE customer_id = 14438 
GROUP BY wt.customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
With cte as
(
    select customer_id as customers_id, sum(amount) as manual_amount,
    (select amount from customers where id = customers_id) as current_wallet_amount,
    FROM wallet_transactions 
    where customer_id = 14438 
    group by wallet_transactions.customer_id
)

select  customers_id,manual_amount,current_wallet_amount,
manual_amount-current_wallet_amount as difference
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cu.id AS customers_id, 
       SUM(wt.amount) AS manual_amount, 
       cu.amount AS current_wallet_amount,
       SUM(wt.amount) - cu.amount AS difference
FROM wallet_transactions AS wt
JOIN customers cu ON cu.id = wt.customer_id
WHERE cu.id = 14438 
GROUP BY cu.id, cu.amount
```